# Passing a static selected list to different textboxes

Tags: list, static, textbox

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>list</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var split="Grand Hotel,Promenade,Southend,Postcode".split(',');
var hotel=split[0];
var street=split[1];
var town=split[2];
var postcode=split[3]
</script>
</script> 
<script>var split="Imperial Hotel,Main St,Dundee,Postcode".split(',');
var hotel=split[0];
var street=split[1];
var town=split[2];
var postcode=split[3]
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('li').click(function () {
console.log($(this).text());
$('#hotel').val($(this).text());
});
}
);

</script> 
<style>
.ui-menu { width: 250px; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#menu" ).menu();
});
</script>
<style>
.ui-menu { width: 250px; }
</style>
</head>
</body>
<body>

<div id="locationselect">
<ul>
<li>Grand Hotel,Promenade,Southend,Postcode</li>
<p>
<li>Imperial Hotel,Main St,Dundee,Postcode</li>
<p>
</ul>
</div>

<input type="text" id="split[0]"/>
<p>
<input type="text" id="split[1]"/>
<p>
<input type="text" id="split[2]"/>
<p>
<input type="text" id="split[3]"/>
<p>
</body>
</html>
```

I knew nothing about coding until I joined a coarse two weeks ago and have got a bit ahead of myself lol but i'm really enjoying the problem solving in working things out, i've got far too much time on my hands. I'm trying to work out a way of selecting and splitting a static list and then passing this into seperate textboxes. Any help would be very much appreciated, I have looked and as far as I can tell i'm the first to ask this specific question, woo hoo!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.selectableItem').click(function () {
//alert('txt=' + $(this).text());
var selected = $(this).text().split(",");
console.log(selected);
$('#location').val(selected[0]);
$('#location2').val(selected[1]);
$('#location3').val(selected[2]);
$('#location4').val(selected[3]);
});
}
);
</script>
```

Comment: This selects the string and split it just name a few text boxes and get the output, now to try and figure out how it would work in a drop down list lol.